# Why doesn't Xcode debugger display type info?

Tags: ios, xcode, gdb, lldb

Many times Xcode will not display instance member values in the watch window.  If I have a type derived from NSObject with a dozen data members, when I click on the wedge to show the members in my class, it will only display the object as an NSObject.

In the example below, I have an array of Search objects.  The debugger clearly seems to understand that the objects in the array are Search objects, but when I click the wedge to expand the Search objects, it just says "Sorry.  These are NSObjects."  Am I doing something wrong or is the Apple debugger technology just 15 years old?

[image]

Comment: For the amount of effort they say they put in the new `lldb` debugger, I often wonder the same thing... In situations like these, I try to call `- description` on the dictionaries in the debugger console (after providing the casts that it asks for, because the console can't tell what it's looking at either). Other times, I have better luck with [AppCode](http://www.jetbrains.com/objc/).

Comment: It may not be solely `lldb`'s fault, but also XCode's. In most cases, typing something like `po [paSearches objectAtIndex:2]` in the debug window works, even when XCode doesn't understand the object type.

Comment: What version of Xcode are you using?  Xcode has become much better at showing instance variables in Xcode 4.4 and 4.5.  If you are using anything older than those, upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using LLDB or GDB? Because those children don't look like LLDB-generated at all.

Comment: I was still using Xcode 4.2.1.  I upgraded but it is still exhibiting this behavior.  How do I tell what debugger I'm using?

Comment: you should have a debugger Console to the right of the Variables view - does it say (lldb) or (gdb)?